# Add inline CSS except for a specific country in Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation

I would like to add css style in my woocommerce website if country is not France because i need to hide a button in all countries except France. I tried the code below

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_state_FR' , 'custom_css_countries', 10, 1 );
function custom_css_countries($mycss) {
  $country = array('FR');
  if( ! in_array( $country ) ){
    echo '<style>#payez-sur-12-mois{display:none;}</style>';
  }
  return $mycss;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to use WC_Geolocation class for this. Instead you can use `WC_Customer` class which already uses the `WC_Countries` and `WC_Geolocation` classes in following hooked function:

```
add_action( 'wp_head' , 'custom_inline_css', 200 );
function custom_inline_css() {
    // For all countries except 'FR'
    if( WC()->customer->get_billing_country() !== 'FR'  )
        ?><style>#payez-sur-12-mois{display:none !important;}</style><?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Updated** - If you really want to use **geolocation**, use this instead:

```
add_action( 'wp_head' , 'custom_inline_css', 200 );
function custom_inline_css() {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
    $geolocation_instance = new WC_Geolocation();
    // Get user IP
    $user_ip_address = $geolocation_instance->get_ip_address();
    // Get geolocated user IP country code.
    $user_geolocation = $geolocation_instance->geolocate_ip( $user_ip_address );

    // For all countries except 'FR'
    if( $user_geolocation['country'] !== 'FR' ){
        ?><style>#payez-sur-12-mois{display:none !important;}</style><?php
    }
    // For testing (to be removed):
    echo '<!-- GEO Located country: '.$user_geolocation['country'].' -->';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Geo IP related answer:

- [Disable payment gateways based on user country geo-ip in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954740/disable-payment-gateways-based-on-user-country-geo-ip-in-woocommerce/49955799?s=1|0.0000#49955799)
- [Change add to cart button based on IP-adress (GeoLocation) in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49793939/change-add-to-cart-button-based-on-ip-adress-geolocation-in-woocommerce/49801968#49801968)

Comment: not working for me! if( ! country_geo_ip_check( array('FR') )  ) should i add $ before country_geo_ip_check?

Comment: @Elichy Ok just make some changes again. This time it works just fine as expected.