# Catalogue mode for variable products based on geolocation in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to enable catalogue mode for a WooCommerce shop for users located everywhere but Australia.

The store has 2 types of products

- simple
- variable

I have tried *"[Turn Woocommerce shop into catalog for geolocated countries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251140/turn-woocommerce-shop-into-catalog-for-geolocated-countries/51254100#51254100)"* answer code, and it works well for "simple" products

**The issue is that variable products still show the quantity field and add to cart button although they are not purchasable.**

---

My understanding is that catalogue mode is essentially making products non purchasable.

If I could inform the code to look for product type "variable" using something like `$product->is_type( 'variable' )` it could apply to both types of product.

---

> I tried this which obviously did not work. Most likely the function cannot accept multiple variables:

```php
//Disable purchasing of products if the country is not Australia
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'purchasable_country_based', 10, 2);
function purchasable_country_based( $is_purchasable, $product, $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    // Enable for "AU" only geolocated users country
    if( get_geolocated_user_country() ==='AU' )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

---

> So I am thinking I could add another instance of the code but to target variable products this time. I tried the following but it also did not work:

```php
//Disable variable products if the country is not Australia
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'purchasable_country_based', 10, 2);
function purchasable_country_based( $is_purchasable, $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    // Enable for "AU" only geolocated users country
    if( get_geolocated_user_country() ==='AU' )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to adapt that code to your needs? stackoverflow is not a 'code writing service' [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have edited my question trying to give more details on what I have tried. I have no experience in php, I realise my question gave the impression that I was aiming for free code, which was not my intention. Thanks for giving it another look

Comment: Sorry but the mentioned answer code works perfectly **for any product type** and remove (or disable on variable products) add to cart button and empty / disable cart if there is any item on it… I have tested that on last Wordpress and WooCommerce versions on Last update of the storefront theme, and more specifically for variable products … So there is something in your installation that is making an issue… it can be your theme, a plugin or some custom code.